# How to format a string with 1000s separator and zeros after comma in C#

Tags: c#

I want to format a string with 1000's separator and also two decimal places by default

I tried this one but it's not working as it fails to append two zeros when there are no decimals

```
String.Format("{0:#,##0.##}", money); //I want something like 1000.23 and also 1000.00
```

Comment: You've already used `0` as a placeholder in your string. Why don't you use it for decimals too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be sure you're not making this more complicated then necessary

```
String.Format("{0:f2}", money);
```

Maybe [standard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) number format is enough and [custom](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx) number format is not needed. But as mentioned if your Culture has a `,` as seperator, this won't work.

Comment: You should also include `CultureInfo` in the call to be sure.

Comment: @kiziu *which* CultureInfo? The application's locale will be used by default. Typically, that's the correct option when formatting for display. `InvariantCulture` is used when the string is used for storage or communicating with other programs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, The one that will correctly present the value according to the requirements. Nowhere does the OP say if the application locale will format the value correctly. That is why I did not specify which `CultureInfo`, only that one should be provided to ensure correct formatting.

Comment: I wnat to have a comma after 1000's also, how should I do it?

Comment: @Shan that would be `String.Format("{0:n2}", money)`

Comment: Go string interpolation! `$"{money:n2}"`